# How to judge the shallow and deep copy? What is the difference?

Tags: python, list, copy

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4]

b = a
c = a[:]
d = list(a)
```

What's the difference for the three assignments?  When shall I use `[:]`?

Comment: `a[:]` or `list(a)` perform a shallow copy.

Comment: People who are more knowledgable please correct me if I am wrong but, the difference is that when you do a shallow copy you are actually using the same underlining array of data so if you change the copy you change the original as well. While deep copy creates a completely different array so changing it does not affect the original. 

shallow copy is like giving you a copy of the house's address for you to access it while deep copy is like making a completely identical house.

Comment: What is the difference for the two shallow copy? When shall I use `[:]` generally?

Comment: Just to make it clear, `b = a` is not shallow nor a deep copy. What you are doing there is just assign the reference to the same in-memory list to both variables `a` and `b`. A shallow copy is when you create new in-memory copies of all elements in `a` but you don't create a new copy for any referenced objects that `a` may contain (that is what `a[:]` and `list[a]` do). For further reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

Comment: @kkawabat no, with a shallow copy, you create *a new underlying array* (or list object, really, but yes, a whole new buffer underneath the hood) but that list contains the same objects as the list being copied. A deep copy recursively copies all the objects in the container/object as well.